# What is the difference in design between a von Neumann and the Harvard's machines?

Tags: computer-architecture, instruction-set

Although there are many webpages talkink about the difference between the Aiken (prototype: Harvard Mark I) and von Neumann (prototype: ENIAC) architecture, the actual divergence remain uncertain to me. I understand that the former is the archetype of the RISC/ARM processors, the latter is the precursor of the CISC processors. If these concepts are correct, I am confused about the structural differences between these architectures.

Harvard Mark I used a single control tape containing holes specificing both instructions and data. Each sector was subdivided into three areas: an ‘out-relay’, an ‘in-relay’ and a ‘miscellaneous’. The out-relay and in-relay would have selected the input data (in the form of arrays of relays); the miscellaneous was intended to provide control over the operation: for instance the code ‘32’ would have meant to subtract the inputs instead of adding them. The Harvard Mark I, therefore, had a single tape reader.

My question is: how was instead the ENIAC structured? I understand it had two separate memories, thus I gather it must have had two tapes and two tape readers, but how were the instructions structured on the tapes?

Is there some good book/tutorial on ENIAC and its design?

Thank you

Comment: ENIAC was neither Harvard or VN architecture as the terms are used now : it was not a stored program computer.There have also been CISC Harvard and many RISC VN machines so the premise of the question needs some clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that the former is the archetype of the RISC/ARM processors, the latter is the precursor of the CISC processors. If these concepts are correct, I am confused about the structural differences between these architectures.

No, that's completely wrong.

[Wikipedia's *Harvard Architecture* article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture) explains the difference quite clearly:

> The Harvard architecture is a computer architecture with separate storage and signal pathways for instructions and data. It contrasts with the von Neumann architecture, where program instructions and data share the same memory and pathways.

So, it's about separate paths for data and instructions. It has nothing to do with CISC/RISC; RISC and CISC processors exist in both architectures (as the architecture really has nothing to do with the "richness" of the instruction set).

Also, the term "RISC" is an invention of the 1980s, if I'm not mistaken. You're trying to apply labels to computers that simply didn't exist in the 1940s, when these computers were built, for more than 30 years after...

> I understand it had two separate memories,

Just like most other machines, it has different kinds of memories, yes: things like accumulator registers, and an "input" memory; later, magnetic memory was added.

> thus I gather it must have had two tapes and two tape readers,

no, that isn't meant with "multiple memories".

> but how were the instructions structured on the tapes?

ENIAC didn't use paper tape at all, it used a switchboard for the operator to set the contents of registers; you can research a lot about these on the internet and wikipedia especially. You'll also find a lot about early encodings for text and numeral data on there.

> Is there some good book/tutorial on ENIAC and its design?

Certainly; I'd recommend starting with the "References" and "Further Reading" section on the [ENIAC wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ENIAC).

Comment: I read the book "ENIAC in action" and truly I got it all wrong. Am I now right in saying that (a) Harvard mark I used multiple buses to read data and instructions simultaneously (b) ENIAC used an accumulator to choose the operation to perform. In general, is the sketch http://cubeupload.com/im/gigux/architect.jpg correct?